# Are there open source libraries to build audio visualizations for iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, visualization, core-audio

I have an equalizer view with 10 bars in OpenGL ES which can light up and down. Now I'd like to drive this equalizer view from the background music that is playing in iOS.

Someone suggested what I need is a [Fast Fourier Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform) to transform the audio data into something else. But since there are so many audio visualizations floating around, my hope is that there is an open source library or anything that I could start with.

Maybe there are open source iOS projects which do audio visualization?

Comment: You keep asking the same question, slightly modified multiple times, not cool.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

You can try [this Objective-C library](https://github.com/tomer8007/real-time-audio-fft) which I wrote for exactly this purpose. What it does is to give you an interface for playing files from `URL`s and then getting real-time FFT and waveform data so that you can feed it with your OpenGL bars or whatever graphics you're using to visualise the sound. It also tries to deliver very accurate results.

If you want to do it in swift, you can take a look at [this example](https://github.com/jscalo/tempi-fft) which is cleaner and also shows how it's possible to actually draw the equalizer view.